# Notepad ++ search and replace multiple text lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

Notepad++ Search And Replace Multiple Text Lines

I have multiple lines like the one in below

Example :

```
set srcaddr  "10.68.0.244/32" "172.29.54.0/25" "PING" permit log set
srcaddr  "172.21.24.110/32" "172.29.44.36/32" "udp-5499" permit log
set srcaddr  "10.211.245.0/26" "172.29.35.201/32" "SSH" permit log
```

the ip address in this statement >>  set srcaddr  "10.68.0.244/32" not fixed number it change in the other lines .

I want to make it like this way

```
set srcaddr  "10.68.0.244/32"
set dstaddr   "172.29.54.0/25" "PING" permit log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to search for:

```
srcaddr(\W+)("[0-9\.\/-]+")\W+("[0-9\.\/-]+")(\W+)"
```

and replace it with this:

```
srcaddr\1\2\nset dstaddr\1\3\4"
```

This worked for me in a small test.

#### Example

Input:

```
set srcaddr  "10.68.0.244/32" "172.29.54.0/25" "PING" permit log
set srcaddr  "172.21.24.110/32" "172.29.44.36/32" "udp-5499" permit log
set srcaddr  "10.211.245.0/26" "172.29.35.201/32" "SSH" permit log
set srcaddr  "172.29.35.201/32" "10.74.79.0/27" "tcp-22" permit log
set srcaddr  "172.29.44.0/24" "172.20.250.0/24" "PING" permit log
set srcaddr  "172.29.35.1/32" "172.21.24.0/24" "tcp-12001" permit log
set srcaddr "172.29.41.0/24" "10.32.125.50-150" "HTTP" permit log
```

Output:

```
set srcaddr  "10.68.0.244/32"
set dstaddr  "172.29.54.0/25" "PING" permit log
set srcaddr  "172.21.24.110/32"
set dstaddr  "172.29.44.36/32" "udp-5499" permit log
set srcaddr  "10.211.245.0/26"
set dstaddr  "172.29.35.201/32" "SSH" permit log
set srcaddr  "172.29.35.201/32"
set dstaddr  "10.74.79.0/27" "tcp-22" permit log
set srcaddr  "172.29.44.0/24"
set dstaddr  "172.20.250.0/24" "PING" permit log
set srcaddr  "172.29.35.1/32"
set dstaddr  "172.21.24.0/24" "tcp-12001" permit log
set srcaddr "172.29.41.0/24"
set dstaddr "10.32.125.50-150" "HTTP" permit log
```

Comment: "PING" also is not fixed

Comment: Could you add two more test cases? I made it as restrictive as possible to avoid replacing other rules.

Comment: Here three different lines 

Examples::

set srcaddr  "10.202.0.0/16" "172.29.42.210/28" "tcp-20-23" permit log
set srcaddr  "10.74.82.32/28" "172.29.35.71/32" "SSH" permit log
set srcaddr  "10.47.7.57/32" "172.29.33.195/32" "tcp-10164-10213" permit log

Comment: Please join [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era), I guess this goes faster, ah sh.. you have too less reputation. Did you select the option regex in the search and replace dialog? Does nothing happen? Or is the result broken?

Comment: it's working only with few polices lines not all

Comment: Can you add lines which doesn't work?

Comment: i have added it to the question up there as example because it's more than 20.000 lines i cant add them all here

Comment: I added my in and output of my test which is successful.

Comment: set srcaddr "172.29.35.201/32" "10.74.79.0/27" "tcp-22" permit log
- 
set srcaddr "172.29.44.0/24" "172.20.250.0/24" "PING" permit log

Comment: set srcaddr "172.29.35.1/32" "172.21.24.0/24" "tcp-12001" permit log

Comment: Added even those cases. Seems to work. I just added in my rule another space for optical reasons. I update the regex to make it more robust against varying whitespace combinations.

Comment: So now I support multiple whitespace variations, if this was the reason it should work now.

Comment: it worked with too much entries but still some didn't work with them like this one >>> set srcaddr "172.29.41.0/24" "10.32.125.50-150" "HTTP" permit log

Comment: This one was easy to fix.